# Git: getting back to unstaged changes after pushing to remote branch?

Tags: git

So I had a changes to a bunch of files, and then created a new branch and pushed them to a new remote branch as follows:

```
git status
    # lots of changes listed
git checkout -b new-branch
git add .
git commit -m "pushing to new-branch"
git push origin new-branch
```

However, when I go back to my master branch, running `git status` results in:

`nothing to commit, working directory clean`, and my changes are all gone. I was under the impression that I would still have all of my changes listed, un-staged. (It's occurred to me that all of my changes got moved over to my 'new-branch'.) Is there any way to get back to this status of having all of my unstaged changes, on the master branch?

Thanks.

Comment: Changes are not staged (or unstaged) *on a branch*, they are simply staged.  Once committed, they are no longer staged at all, they're just committed.  Is that the source of this confusion?  If not, I don't understand the question at all.

Comment: It seems you have trouble understanding some of the basics of git; I suggest you to read the ["The Three States"](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Git-Basics#The-Three-States) subchapter of the gitpro book. It's fundamental to understand this concept if you want to use git effectively.

Answer (score 0):

When you committed your changes to the new branch, you have no more unstaged changes. No matter on which branch you are (or you switch in between making changes) once you do commit, all your staged changes (`git add`) will get committed to the current branch.

However in your case if you need all your last committed changes back in your master branch, you can perform a rollback (`git reset --soft`). By making this you'll delete the last commit made on your branch `new-branch`

```
git checkout new-branch
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

This will rollback your last commit on the branch and the changes you made will be available in staging.

Now you can checkout master and make your additional changes and commit again.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands:

1. git checkout new-branch
2. git reset --soft HEAD^
3. git checkout master
4. git status

If your are lying before some commits then try this instead of step 2:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~3
```

which reverts the changes specified by the fourth last commit in HEAD. (You need to change the number '3' based on the position of your unwanted commit.)

And check git status. You should be able to see your local changes, which is yet to be committed.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to get back to this status of having all of my unstaged changes, on the master branch?

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this.  **I don't recommend it**, but this will do the trick:

```
git checkout master # go back to the master branch
git merge new-branch # merge in the changes you committed in new-branch
git reset --soft HEAD~1 # make HEAD point to the commit before the merge
                        # this will leave the changes in the index, 
                        # in other words, staged
```

you can also replace the last command with

```
git reset --mixed HEAD~1 # make HEAD point to the commit before the merge
                        # this will leave no changes in the index, 
                        # in other words, no changes are staged
```

I do recommend that you learn about the three states: committed, modified, and staged.  Read [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Git-Basics).